# Unable to terminate a subnet on Oracle Cloud

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to terminate a subnet on oracle cloud but I get this issue:

The Subnet ocid1.subnet.oc1.iad.aaaaaaaaxzhssdvwh4pc2pk7uwpyokeluklqkdqcjnsib7idmdp7wkh7o5iq references the VNIC ocid1.vnic.oc1.iad.abuwcljs2ggk7yk4fpvvytdt74ya7wolg3xwoz4nauryrifd3dl4t4cfbonq. You must remove the reference to proceed with this operation.

I haven't been able to find out how to remove the VNIC reference.
Thx

[oracle cloud vcn issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ4MR.png)

Comment: Facing the same issue. The below option wouldn't work. It seems somehow, there's no resolution yet in the public domain.

Comment: Got the same issue after peering two VCNs. Now I can't destroy one of the subnets.

Answer (score 2):

FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT

I have figured it out. The disadvantage of using the free tier of Oracle Cloud that I am on is that you don't get any support from Oracle.

steps taken to solve the issue:

1. delete/terminate the internet gateway associated with the Virtual Cloud Network
2. also delete/terminate the service gateway associated with the VCN/Virtual Cloud Network
3. terminate the NAT Gateway
4. remove security lists (you can leave the default security list on)
5. remove route tables (default route table can stay on)
6. terminate the load balancer associated with the subnet
7. NOW you can terminate the subnet
8. finally, terminate the VCN

helpful links: (these links will help but you might have to figure some of it out if you set up your VCN differently than how it is shown in the docs.
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Troubleshoot/subnetdelete.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/File/Troubleshooting/orphanedmounttarget.htm#Cannot_Delete_VCN_Mount_Target_VNIC_Still_Attached

Comment: This is not the case, even if all the resources are removed, the VNIC is still lingering on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and removing all resources under the VNC manually, did not help me. No way to find the reference and where the VNIC is. Then I remembered that I had been using cloudshell's private network under the one of subnets of VNC. Once I stopped using that network for cloudshell, then I can delete the VNC.